# Unable to Install SOAP LITE

Tags: perl, activestate

I've tried to install SOAP::Lite from the Active State's repository but it
gave the following error:

```
ppm install SOAP-Lite
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides SOAP-Lite
```

I read somewhere on Apache dependency but not sure if that is correct. I am using perl version 5.26.3 on windows 7

Regards

Comment: `cpan SOAP::Lite`